# Syslinux boot parameters

Tags: live-cd, syslinux

I'm booting a Debian live system from USB(debian 5.0.3). My syslinux append parameters are:

```
initrd=/live/initrd.img union=aufs persistent noprompt ip=frommedia boot=live noautologin noxautologin quickreboot nouser
```

When I cat /proc/cmdline I get all those parameters, plus BOOT_IMAGE=/live/vmlinuz

The problem is when I boot, the default user is still created and I am auto logged-in. I thought the 'noautologin' and 'noxautologin' should stop that, and 'nouser' should stop the default user from being added to the system. I also thought that 'noprompt' should stop the system from asking me to remove the USB key on reboot, but I had to add the 'quickreboot' for that to happen.

The ip=frommedia works, persistence works, its just the noautologin that seems broken.
Are those old parameters? Do I need to list them in a specific order? Or is this not possible with a live boot?

I've also found some Policy configs that I've tried, still no luck though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after searching everywhere and modifying all the scripts initrd.img, I started over. During the VERY FIRST BOOT I made sure I had persistent, noautologin, and nouser options set. Things seem to work fine now.  But if you use 'persistent' and try to add noautologin later, it just doesn't work. If anyone can be more specific please inform me. But I had to restart with clean live-rw partition to remove whatever was saved that broke this.